# Why this Widget should be returned as List?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, tolist

```
(questionList[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) { 
  return Answer(_textChanger, answer);
}).toList();
```

this code is part of my main.dart. that code is inside of Column(childer:). I want to ask why this code use "toList()"method to return as List?

Comment: Well, being in *your* dart file, shouldn't you know about it? If you did not write it, did you ask the one who did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) children requires list of widgets:

> children → List
> The widgets below this widget in the tree.
> [...] final, inherited

and toList() returns list of Answer widgets